# UL style sheet not wrapping in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, html-lists

I'm using the following style sheet to wrap an UL...it causes the UL to wrap to the top of the next column when it reaches the bottom of the page.

This code works in Chrome but not in IE.

```
#limheight {
height: 350px; /*your fixed height*/
-webkit-column-count: 4;
   -moz-column-count: 4;
        column-count: 4; /*3 in those rules is just placeholder -- can be anything*/          
}
#limheight li {
display: normal; /*necessary*/
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have a look at: http://www.goodbytes.be/blog/article/simple-ie8-and-ie9-fallback-for-css3-multiple-column-layouts

Comment: Check this for Column browser compatibility - http://caniuse.com/multicolumn

Comment: SW4 thanks for the link that's a good start...I've read what posted on that page and see the general way it works but I'm missing something...

Once Modernizr detects that a browser does not support columns it appears to add a class to the HTML element. And in the example on that page he then shows this css code definition for that class..but I don't understand if the older browser does not support multiple columns then how does this help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be using Internet Explorer 10 or above. If you are using Internet Explorer 9 or below, then the columns will not display as it does not support all CSS3 functions.

Comment: Thanks I have verified that it works in IE 10 and 11. Unfortunately most of our clients our still using older versions of IE.